# Custom autoClosingBrackets in Visual Studio Code

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to make it so that when I'm editing LaTeX and enter a '$' character it automatically places another '$' and puts the cursor between them, just like with '"', '(', '[', '{', and '/*'.

I've been trying to find how to do this. Do I have to remake the extension or something?

The ideal solution would be a keyword like:

```
"latex-workshop.autoCloseBracketChars":"{}()$$ etc."
```